# How to know which field is saved when only() has been used in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.11, in one of my models I have added actions when the model is saved.

However I don't want these actions to be done when only a part of the model is saved.

I know that `update_fields=('some_field',)` can be used to specify which field must be saved.
But, when the object has been fetched in the database using the methods `only() or defer()` I don't see any information about the fields updated in the `save()` method, `update_fields` is empty.

Thus my question: How can I get the fields saved by Django when only some fields have been fetched ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `defer` or `only` to load an instance, the `get_deferred_fields()` method returns a list of field names that have not been loaded; you should be able to use this to work out which ones will be saved.